# How to convert hex to decimal using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, number-formatting

How do i convert hex values to their decimal value using nodejs ?

Suppose i have hex value as bellow

```
9c63e8e2f6574c197c0626bad843eb47104adf3f01f2901aad1258936feb007e
```

Any one have any idea the please let me know

Comment: bash? php? Any reason for these tags?

Comment: @jeroen Kindly check i have updated tag

Answer (score 13):

JS parseInt function takes base as a second argument. 
So you can simply use `parseInt(hexString, 16)`.

For example: `parseInt('ff', 16)` will return 255.

Comment: One note is that `parseInt` yields a number, which in JavaScript is a float. Hence, large numbers will lose precision. E.g.: `parseInt("3C1EBED3AC00205", 16)` yields `270756856744378880` instead of `270756856744378885`. Also see https://www.danvk.org/hex2dec.html